# Check if there is only one of two types of files in a directory

Tags: bash, ls

I have a script that checks if there is only one file in a directory. However, I can't figure out how to check if there is only one executable (no file extension) or script (.sh) in that directory. Here's what I currently have:

```
loc=(/Applications/*)
APPROOTDIR="${loc[RANDOM % ${#loc[@]}]}/"
APPDIR="${APPROOTDIR}Contents/MacOS/"
echo "APPROOTDIR is ${APPROOTDIR}"
echo "APPDIR is ${APPDIR}"
FIAD=$(ls ${APPDIR})
if [ `ls -1 ${APPDIR}* 2>/dev/null | wc -l ` == 1 ]; then
    echo "One executable or script: ${FIAD}"
else
    echo "Not one executable or script: ${FIAD}"
fi
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Sorry, executable as in a the file that is ran when a macOS application is launched. It's always located in the directory APPNAME.app/Contents/MacOS/

Comment: I don't see what the file extension has to do with whether a file is an executable, respectively a binary. To test whether a file is an executable, use [[ -x FILENAME ]]. To see whether it is a script or a binary, can only be determined heuristically, for instance by parsing the output of `file FILENAME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), populate another array with the directory entries and work on it instead.

```
shopt -s nullglob
# set up loc, APPDIR, etc. here
ent=("$APPDIR"*)
if [[ ${#ent[@]} -eq 1 && ( $ent = *.sh || -x $ent ) ]]; then
  echo 'One executable or script: '
else
  echo 'Not one executable or script: '
fi
printf '%q\n' "${ent[@]#"$APPDIR"}"
```

Note that variables with all uppercase names are reserved for shells, it's recommended to use lower or mixed-case variable names.